# Global 404 Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, 404

In SharePoint Online, is there a way to create a Tenant wide 404 page? I know you can do it in individual site collections on publishing libraries but I would like the same 404 page for all site collections. For example, these should all display the same 404 page.

https://.sharepoint.com/sites/nonexistentpage.aspx 
https://.sharepoint.com/sites/subsite/nonexistentpage.aspx 
https://.sharepoint.com/teams/nonexistentpage.aspx
https://.sharepoint.com/nonexistentpage.aspx